# HTML how to get tag arguments

Tags: html, tags, arguments

My English is weak so I give an example.
I want something like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>MySite</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="mydiv" testarg="teststring"></div>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var argstring = getArgument(element,"testarg");
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should be,

```
var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var argstring = element.getAttribute("testarg");
```

Alternatively, you can use **[data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)** which is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. `data-*` attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM

So, your code will be like,

```
<div id="mydiv" data-testarg="teststring"></div>
<script>
   var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
   var argstring = article.dataset.testarg;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getAttribute` to get an attribute's value, and `setAttribute` to set it (change it):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MySite</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mydiv" testarg="teststring"></div>
  <script>
    var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var argstring = element.getAttribute('testarg');
    console.log(argstring);
    
    element.setAttribute('testarg', 'changed');
    
    console.log(element.getAttribute('testarg'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var argstring = element.getAttribute('testarg');
console.log(argstring );
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" testarg="teststring"></div>
```